# I can not continue with a task

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new in Java and need your help with my homework.
Here is the task:

```
class F {
    private static int x = 0;
    public static int funcB(int z){
        return ++x + z;
    }

    public static int func(int x) {
        x = x + 2;
        x = funcB(x);
        return x++;
    }
}
```

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int z = 2;
        int x = F.func(z);
        System.out.println(z);
        System.out.println(x);

        x = F.func(x + z);
        System.out.println(x);

    }
}
```

Why is x = 5?

Comment: This is what desk checking is for - when in doubt, write it out

Comment: You have 3 *different* variables named as `x` which may confuse you. Start by renaming them to better understand your code.

Comment: Also if you still need help after than consider specifying what other value you expected and *why*. This can help us see mistake in your assumptions so we could focus on it without spending time on explaining parts which you already know.

Comment: x is 5 when the first System.out.println(x) is printed when I run your code through the debugger. I did it in C# but I'm assuming it would be the same.  Set a breakpoint on each method and observe the values.

Comment: @Pshemo - since this is homework, I imagine the point is to understand the scoping rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, write it out.  So we start with...

```
int z = 2;
int x = F.func(z);
```

which calls...

```
public static int func(int x) {
    x = x + 2;
    x = funcB(x);
    return x++;
}
```

So, the input of `x` is `2`

- `x = x + 2` = `2 + 2` = `4`, so `x` is now 4
- `x = funcB(x)`

which calls...

```
public static int funcB(int z) {
    return ++x + z;
}
```

- Then input of `z` is `4`
- `++x + z`, `x` is `0`
- `++x` is a "prefix" increment, meaning that the increment will be applied BEFORE the rest of the statement is executed, making `x` = `1`
- `1 + z` = `1 + 4` = `5`

Back to `func`

- `return x++;` is a trick (and a common area of mistakes), `x++` is a "postfix" addition, meaning that `x` will be incremented AFTER the statement is executed (for the sake of the argument), meaning that the method will return `5`

Comment: it's all so confusing :(

Comment: Welcome to the forest, look out for trees

Comment: Can you explain me in detail why in the last System.out.printIn (x) comes out? :/

Comment: `F.x` is `static`, so it retains the value assigned to it across multiple calls

Answer (score 1):

The reason why x is 5 in your main method lies in the subtle `x++`.
The return statement combined with x++ is the trick because x++ means that first you use x in the current instruction, then you increment it by one. Your code would be expanded to
    Return x;
    X = x + 1